# Retrieve total time of editing of word document

Tags: c#, sql, ms-word

I need to store total time of editing in my database.

Is there a way to retrieve this timespan, when a user uploads a document?.

I use visual studio c# and SQL as my database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can inspect the property by the same name.  Not sure exactly how to call it in C#, but it can be accessed in this manner using VBA -
ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Total Editing Time").Value
This should work for most recent versions of Word.